# Calling a time server to just look at the time

Tags: c#, time, cmd

Apologies in advance if this has been answered before, I did look but struggled to find anything that answered my question.

I'm currently creating an application in C# and one of the things I would like it to do is display the local time and also the time from a time server.

So to be clear, I am not trying to use the server time FOR anything. I literally just want to display it on the windows form. (as a side note I am not sure what time server to use yet but it just needs to be a public UK time server)

I've looked into getting C# to query it on its own; but by my own shallow understanding it seems there is no simple way to do this.

Is there anyway I could perhaps just use command line to get the time server and then echo that to a .txt file? Even this simple solution would sort my issue but im struggling to wade through all the information surrounding w32tm.

Thanks very much in advance,
Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance but I've found a relatively simple way to do this from this question.
https://superuser.com/questions/451018/how-can-i-query-an-ntp-server-under-windows

I can now just echo out the server time.

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 0):

How about [SNTP](http://dotnet-snippets.com/snippet/simple-network-time-ntp-protocol-client/571) client, which a C# implementation of the SNTP.

Comment: Im sure that I could get what i'm looking for from that. But it seems like an overly complicated way to do a fairly simple thing. Literally, via any means, get the time from the time server in a text file or anything. Just somewhere.